# Efficiently calculating integral of a multivariate function on non-rectangular region?

Tags: r, integration

I want to compute the expected value of a multivariate function `f(x)` wrt to [dirichlet distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution). My problem is "penta-nomial" (i.e 5 variables) so calculating the explicit form of the expected value seems unreasonable. Is there a way to numerically integrate it efficiently?

```
f(x) = \sum_{0,4}(x_i*log(n/x_i))
```

`x = <x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4>` and `n` is a constant

Comment: Library / software recommendations are typically considered off-topic for SO - this question may get closed.

Comment: Thanks for heads up! I changed the question...

Comment: Is q_i, or n, a known function of x?

Comment: Could you post the analytic function that you are trying to integrate (and the domain)?

Comment: The x = <x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4> where \sum_{0,4}x_i = 1

Comment: Does the last example from this [link](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jyang06/stat401/handouts/handout8.pdf) provide enough information to answer the question?

Comment: Interesting point, I did see the cubature package but cubature works only when integrating over rectangular regions here however that is not the case ;_;